# Multi-Dimensional Data Results Using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, multidimensional-array, olap

I would like to know if I can write an sql query that can generate multi-dimensional result set as shown below.

[image]

I am sure this can be done using OLAP, but i have no practical knowledge on OLAP.

I wrote my query as follows:

```
select sfrstcr_term_code term, 
stvrsts_desc reg_status,
count(distinct SFRSTCR_PIDM) count
from sfrstcr,stvrsts 
where sfrstcr_term_code = 201401 
and SFRSTCR_ADD_DATE > to_date('21/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
and SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE is not null
and sfrstcr_camp_code = 'L'
and stvrsts_code = SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE
group by sfrstcr_term_code, stvrsts_desc

union

select sfrstcr_term_code term, 
stvrsts_desc reg_status,
count(distinct SFRSTCR_PIDM) count
from sfrstcr,stvrsts 
where sfrstcr_term_code = 201301 
and SFRSTCR_ADD_DATE > to_date('22/02/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
and SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE is not null
and sfrstcr_camp_code = 'L'
and stvrsts_code = SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE
group by sfrstcr_term_code, stvrsts_desc

union

select sfrstcr_term_code term, 
stvrsts_desc reg_status,
count(distinct SFRSTCR_PIDM) count
from sfrstcr,stvrsts 
where sfrstcr_term_code = 201201 
and SFRSTCR_ADD_DATE > to_date('24/02/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')
and SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE is not null
and sfrstcr_camp_code = 'L'
and stvrsts_code = SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE
group by sfrstcr_term_code, stvrsts_desc

order by 2,1
```

The result for the above query is as:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your 3 union clause are identical except for the date portion...you can rewrite that to be one statement with a group by clause pretty readily.  The second part...you are looking for a 'pivot'.  Google (or search here on SO) for oracle pivot

Comment: Thanks @Twelfth Pivot works fine for me.